# Multi Boot USB Stick

Tags: usb-flash-drive, multi-boot, bootloader, bootable-media

I have several Boot CD's/DVD's where I'm able to make a bootable USB-stick and put into it. But I can do this separately only. Is it possible to merge several bootable CD's/DVD's into a single bootable USB-stick where I can choose which system to boot from? I'll be happy for a good link, or if you just tell me the steps with the right expressions that i can google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible, try out a great application called [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) it allows you to make a long boot list with an iso if you have it, you can even use unsupported bootable iso's to be included.

Comment: Really cool tool, and also very useful web site. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This possible using a bootloader like grub - or if you are working with Windows [grub4dos](http://gna.org/projects/grub4dos/)

In the config file you can add multiple ISO images you can select from in the boot menu.

Another nice tool for Windows is [RMPrepUSB](http://reboot.pro/7739/) for which you can find a [video tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wX6BHnefIms) that shows how to create a bootable USB-Stick. By editing the menu.lst you can add multiple ISO images.

Alternatively if you prefer a clean hardware sulution take a look onto the [ISOStick](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/elegantinvention/isostick-the-optical-drive-in-a-usb-stick) - an USB stick that includes an hardware emulated usb cd/dvd-drive booting from an ISO contained on the stick.